# select user and then dropdown of his challenges

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby

A user `has_many` challenges.

When a user is selected...

```
<%= f.select :user_id, options_for_select(@challengers.collect { |challenger| [challenger.full_name] }) %>
```

... how can we show another dropdown with a list of his challenges?

```
<%= f.select :challenge_id, options_for_select(@challenger_challenges.collect { |challenged| [challenged.full_challenge]}) %>
```

In other words, how can we make "`@challenger_challenges` = the selected user's challenges"?

As it stand I get an error `undefined method 'collect' for nil:NilClass` since `@challenger_challenges` is `nil`.

### OPTION 1

In challenges_controller I could do this:

```
@challengers = User.all
@challenger = User.find(params[:challenger_selected]) if (params[:challenger_selected]).present?
@challenger_challenges = @challenger.challenges
```

And then I would just need a way to refresh the page once a user is selected so that the user ID is passed in the params as `:challenger_selected`

### OPTION 2

Achieve the aim of this question without the need of a page refresh. *Preferable

### UPDATE

Based upon the comments below I realize I need to elaborate.

A user `has_many` challenges.

A user can create a `duel`.

In a `duel` there are two `duelers`.

The creator of the `duel` selects his own `:challenge_id` and then he selects the other dueler as well as one of his `:challenge_id` and then sets the `@duel.consequence` the dueler will have to do if he fails his challenge. The other dueler will get a duel request notification and then has the choice to accept or decline the conditions of the duel.

**challenges.show.html.erb**

```
<%= render 'duels/form' %>
```

**duels/_form.html.erb**

```
<%= simple_form_for(@duel) do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :duelers do |dueler| %> 
    <%= f.hidden_field :challenge_id, :value => @challenge.id %>
    <%= @challenge.full_challenge %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.fields_for :duelers do |dueler| %>
    <%= render 'duels/dueler_fields', :f => dueler %>
  <% end %>
  <%= button_tag(type: 'submit', class: "btn", id: "challenge-create-save")  do %>
    Request Duel
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

**duels/_dueler_fields.html.erb**

```
<%= f.select :user_id, options_for_select(@challengers.collect { |challenger| [challenger.id] }) %>

# Trying to make this responsive to the user that is selected above
<%= render 'challenges/select', :f => f %>

<script>
$('#duel_duelers_attributes_1_user_id').change(function () {
    var challenger_id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    var address = "<%= select_path %>".concat(challenger_id);
    $.get(address, function(data) {
        $("#duel_duelers_attributes_1_challenge_id").html(data);
    });
});
</script>
```

**routes**

```
get 'challenges/select/:id' => 'challenges#select', as: 'select'
```

**challenges/_select.html.erb**

```
<%= f.select :challenge_id, options_for_select(@challenger_challenges.collect { |challenged| [challenged.full_challenge]}) %>
```

**challenges_controller**

```
def select
  if (params[:challenger_id]).present?
    @challenger = User.find(params[:challenger_id])
  else
    @challenger = User.find(1)
  end
  @challenger_challenges = @challenger.challenges
end
```

Comment: bind a change listener to your first select and do a ajax request to render the 2nd select

Comment: move your `<script...` to the `application.js` (just for better separation). Your `select`will be a separate method in the controller, that only gets `challenger` + `challenges`. In the view you will only render the select box.

Comment: I got it working but I ran into a new problem @Fallenhero http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42464849/j-rendered-collection-select-outputs-html-tags

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Credit for this should go to @Fallenhero - I am just explaining it in more detail.

You need to be able to identify the select tag.

```
<%= f.select ..., :html => {:id => :first} %>
```

You also need somewhere to put the second one.

```
<div id="second"></div>
```

Using jQuery:

```
$('#first').change(function () {
    var challenger_id = $(this).find(":selected").val();
    var address = "<%= [prints address to new select tag] %>".concat(challenger_id);
    $.get(address, function(data) {
        $("#second").html(data);
    });
});
```

The address Ruby prints out should look something like `challenges/select/` depending on how you want to design it. The `/` at the end is important.

Comment: You need to get the route to take a parameter. `get '/challenges/select/:challenger_id'` Does it work now?

Comment: @AnthonyGalli.com ?? when are you getting that error? you should not call your ajax method `show` and dont call your id `challenger_id` because you are already in `challenger`-controller norm would be to just call it `id`

Comment: For context, what are `Duels` and `Challenges`?

Comment: Thank you @SekalfNroc! After some tweaking on your answer I was able to get the javascript working so that the new list of user challenges would be rendered. I ran into a little glitch tho where in the select options the HTML is showing. Do you know how I could resolve this? I think your javascript is causing it. I created a new question for this problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42464849/j-rendered-collection-select-outputs-html-tags Thanks again!